# Working with ExtJs4 combobox in forms

Tags: combobox, extjs4

I have Product edit form, with combobox field definition:

```
 xtype: 'combo',
 fieldLabel: _('Supplier'),
 hideTrigger: true,
 displayField: 'company',
 valueField: 'id',
 name: 'supplier',
 store: 'Supplier',
```

When form loads I use standard feature: form.loadRecord( record ), in combo I see supplier_id ??? If i do selection, there are company. What that happens?

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely the timing. When do you load your `Supplier` store? Is it automatically? Then most likely it's loaded *after* you called `loadRecord`.